# 2017 MacBook Air suddenly wouldn't turn on/wake up

Tags: macbook-pro, power

My MacBook Air drained out of power. Now when I plug it in, it wouldn't start. I have tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM.

One peculiar thing that I noticed is that the MagSafe power cable is showing orange as it is charging. But when I press the Power key, without holding or with holding, it turns to green and then changes back to red.

The Mac is just 1 year 3 months old.

Comment: Have you waited sufficient time for the power light to change from red to orange?

Comment: Its just two colors, right? Green and red/dark orange. The usual two ones.

Comment: When i release power button, it turns from red/orange to green for 1-2 secs and then back to red/orange.